# ogr2ogr + MapInfo TAB + SQLite (SpatiaLite) = unicode problems

Tags: mapinfo, ogr2ogr, tilemill, sqlite, unicode

I'm adding MapInfo TAB files to SQLite (SpatiaLite) database using those arguments:

```
ogr2ogr -f "SQLite" dataset.sqlite somelayer.tab -dsco spatialite=yes
```

Source file `somelayer.tab` have `WindowsCyrillic` encoding defined:

```
!table
!version 450
!charset WindowsCyrillic

Definition Table
  Type NATIVE Charset "WindowsCyrillic"
  Fields 1
    Name Char (100) ;
```

As a result, `dataset.sqlite` have `somelayer` table with `VARCHAR Name` column.

But I need store `Name` values in unicode.

How can I tell `ogr2ogr` use unicode `NVARCHAR` type for `Name` column and encode text from `WindowsCyrillic` (Windows-1251) to `UTF-8` encoding for storing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQLite does not care about types and VARCHAR and NVARCHAR mean just the same for it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3930501/difference-between-varchar-nvarchar-in-sqlite.

The real problem is in the GDAL MapInfo driver that does not handle character encodings. There are some workarounds:

1. Convert MapInfo data into MID/MIF format with ogr2ogr and convert Windows-1251 into UTF-8 with iconv. Conversion with ogr2ogr from MID/MIF (UTF-8) into SpatiaLite should go right now.
2. Alternatively, convert MapInfo data first into GML with ogr2ogr and convert the GML file info UTF-8 with iconv. Finally convert GML into SpatiaLite.

Comment: yes, I currently use slightly modified 1st workaround. I wrote single powershell script to convert whole folder to mif/mid using `og2ogr`, recode it to UTF-8 using .NET (`$text = [IO.File]::ReadAllText($mid, $encoding);` `[IO.File]::WriteAllText($mid, $text, [Text.Encoding]::UTF8);`) and then finally append to SQLite database using `ogr2ogr`. But I was hoping that GDAL MapInfo driver have some key to read specified encdoing and write in UTF-8.

Comment: Had a similar problem going from a Win-1252 .TAB file to Postgres, used option (2) from above. Code follows in case it helps anyone. Convert to GML: `ogr2ogr -f GML original-1252.gml original-1252.TAB --config OGR_FORCE_ASCII NO`  Change encoding: `iconv -f CP1252 -t UTF-8 original-1252.gml >converted-utf8.gml`  Finally load: `ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL %PG_CONECTION_DETAILS% converted-utf8.gml -nln schema.new_table_name`